# Accessing a particular DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How would I access the `<li>jQuery is for chumps!</li>` element?
It does not have an ID so I'm not sure what to do.
I'm going to store it in a variable

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Simplify, Simplify</title>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div> Remember!
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <ol>
                        <li>Start with the function keyword</li>
                        <li>Inputs go between ()</li>
                        <li>Actions go between {}</li>
                        <li>jQuery is for chumps!</li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
                <li>Inputs are separated by commas.</li>
                <li>Inputs can include other functions!</li>
            </ul>
        </div>   
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It can be as easy as `$('li:contains("jQuery is for chumps!")')`. You have many traversal methods at your disposal, use them: https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

Comment: do you want `li` by its content or position?

Comment: what is the selection based on... the content of the `li`, or its position

Comment: @FelixKling just using `li` may not solve the problem as there is a parent `li` also  - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/1db8boq2/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
var selector = $('ol li:last');
```

---

More specific would be adding an id or a class to the parent div and do like this:

```
var selector = $('#parent ol li:last');
```

---

Or, if it can be anywhere in your ol then you can use contains:

```
var selector = $('#parent ol li:contains("jQuery is for chumps!")');
```

Comment: The li you're looking for is actually the last child of an 'ol' not a 'ul'

Comment: Wouldn't that select `<li>Inputs can include other functions!</li>`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple selectors here

```js
//using the contents of the li, using contains() can return partial matches so need to be careful about it
$('ul ol li').filter(':contains("jQuery is for chumps!")').css('color', 'red');
//using the position - it targets the last child of the ol element
$('ul ol li:last-child').css('background-color', 'green');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Remember!
  <ul>
    <li>
      <ol>
        <li>Start with the function keyword</li>
        <li>Inputs go between ()</li>
        <li>Actions go between {}</li>
        <li>jQuery is for chumps!</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li>Inputs are separated by commas.</li>
    <li>Inputs can include other functions!</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without jQuery: `document.getElementsByTagName('li')[5]`

Then you can use an if statement to check whether it has the right content or not.

```
var i = 0;
while(i <= document.getElementsByTagName('li').length()){
   if(document.getElementsByTagName('li')[i].innerHTML == "jQuery is for Chumps"){
      //Do Something
   }
   i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First your HTML, to make query faster-add an id. Otherwise you would have to look from body tag, that could take some time.

```
            <ul id="menu-bar">
                <li>
                    <ol>
                        <li>Start with the function keyword</li>
                        <li>Inputs go between ()</li>
                        <li>Actions go between {}</li>
                        <li>jQuery is for chumps!</li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
                <li>Inputs are separated by commas.</li>
                <li>Inputs can include other functions!</li>
            </ul>
```

And now the selector, either by checking the last node

```
var lastElement = $('#menu-bar > li > ol > li:last');
```

or by content (that will not work if you are supporting many languages)

```
var lastElement = $('#menu-bar > li > ol li:contains("jQuery is for chumps!")')
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the direct children of `ol` element:

```
var children = $("ol > li");
```

Get the specific element:

```
var element = children.last();
```

Get the text from the element:

```
var text = element.html();
```